# trying to make a function that extract emails in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i made this simple code that extract emails from a webpage .
i wanted to convert it to a single function
am having issues doing it , iwatched every yt video, how to convert this code to a function ?

```
   import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re
import sys
sauc = urllib.request.urlopen('https://bluerayheatingandcooling.com/contact.htm').read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauc,'lxml')

vars = soup.get_text()
varr = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.[a-z]{3}',vars)


print(varr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re
import sys
def extract_mails(url):
  sauc = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauc,'lxml')

  vars = soup.get_text()
  varr = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.[a-z]{3}',vars)
  return varr


print(extract_mails('https://bluerayheatingandcooling.com/contact.htm'))
```

Comment: i want to make this function execute for each line in a given file  i tried 
with open('listt.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        extract_mails(line)